# lintr test passes with devtools::check() and fails with devtools::test()

Tags: r, testing, lintr

I am [writing an R package](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap/) with the following lint test:

```r
context("Require no code style errors")
library(lintr)

test_that("Package has no lintr errors", {
    lintr::expect_lint_free()
})
```

The tests pass with `devtools::check():

```
$ Rscript -e "devtools::check()"
...
─  checking tests ...
✔  Running ‘testthat.R’ [61s/65s]
...
0 errors ✔ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔
```

and the lint-free test fails with `devtools::test()`:

```
$ Rscript -e "devtools::test()"
...
Testing PosteriorBootstrap
...
✖ |  0 1     | Require no code style errors [6.2 s]
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
test_lintr.R:5: failure: Package has no lintr errors
Not lint free
tests/testthat/test_anpl.R:112:1: style: Trailing whitespace is superfluous.

^~
...
OK:       20
Failed:   1
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0
```

The problem is that Github and Travis are set to reject pull requests that fail the tests, and that if I run `devtools::test()` after `devtools::check()`, all the other tests run twice.

How can I get `devtools::check()` to run the `lintr` test?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a [known issue](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/811):

> This is not a bug in devtools (but maybe in lintr). `devtools::check()` runs the check in a temporary directory, but `lint_package()` assumes it is being run in a package directory, therefore there are no source files to be linted. ... you can confirm this with `devtools::check(check_dir = ".")`, which should produce linting failures if `devtools::test()` does.

The solution proposed, written in May 2015, no longer works. The issue is now locked and closed, so it's unlikely to be addressed.

I suggest running the check and narrowing the test only to `lintr`:

```sh
Rscript -e "devtools::check();devtools::test_file(file = 'testthat/test_lintr.R')"
```